# Why Master theorem cannot be applied

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

Doing an assignment and stuck on a few questions.

1. T(n) = T(2n/5)+n
2. T(n) = T(2n/3)+T(n/3)+n
3. T(n) = T(n−2)+n

Something tells me that on all of them the Master theorem cannot be applied. But why? And what are their upper bounds (big-Oh)?

Comment: Forgetting all master theorem and math stuff, for the third one, you can solve it by common sense, or by method of substitution, and the answer you find will make sense as the sub-problem is hardly reduced at all

Comment: It is an assignment, yes. But I actually did try attempting it, hence why I said I believe the theorem did not work. I came for guidance and understanding, not to be ridiculed.

Answer (score 5):

The master method works only for following type of recurrences.

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n) where a >= 1 and b > 1
```

For the questions,

**1. T(n) = T(2n/5)+n**

@templatetypedef has already modified this recurrence equation to fit the master theorem as

```
T(n) = T(n / (5/2)) + n
```

I guess you can solve it from here.

**2. T(n) = T(2n/3)+T(n/3)+n**

Clearly this cannot be solved directly by master theorem. We should try constructing the recursion tree and see. A recursion tree diagrams the tree of recursive calls and the amount of work done at each call. 
Following is the image taken from [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html)

[image]

So, this reduces to O(n * log n)

**3. T(n) = T(n−2)+n**

Clearly this cannot be solved directly by master theorem.
There is a modified formula derived for Subtract-and-Conquer type.

This [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/master-theorem-subtract-conquer-recurrences/) might be useful.

For recurrences of form,

```
T(n) = aT(n-b) + f(n)

where n > 1, a>0, b>0
```

If f(n) is O(n<sup>k</sup>) and k>=0, then

1. If a<1 then T(n) = O(n<sup>k</sup>)
2. If a=1 then T(n) = O(n<sup>k+1</sup>)
3. if a>1 then T(n) = O(n<sup>k</sup> * a<sup>n/b</sup>)

I guess you can solve it from here.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The Master Theorem can be applied to any recurrence of the form

> T(n) = aT(n / b) + O(n<sup>d</sup>)

where a, b, and d are constants. (There are some other formulations, but this above one handles the more common cases). Specifically, this means that

- the problem size must shrink by a constant factor,
- the subproblems must all have the same size,
- there must be a constant number of subproblems, and
- the additive term must be a polynomial.

These criteria rule out the second recurrence (the subproblems don't have the same sizes) and the third (the problem size must shrink by a constant factor). However, the first recurrence satisfies all four of these criteria. It might help to rewrite the recurrence as

> T(n) = T(n / (5/2)) + n.

Based on that, what case of the Master Theorem are you in, and what does the recurrence solve to?

Comment: For the (2) question, I saw that it didn't work because there were 2 T's in which they both had 2/3 and 1/3 respectfully. I didn't know where to go from there

Comment: The Master Theorem only applies when all the subproblems have the same size, so as soon as you see something with multiple sizes of subproblems you can rule out applying the Master Theorem, though you can solve the recurrences in other ways.